# Operation frequency

Tags: c, algorithm

For this code

```
int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    if(a[i]==0)
        count++;
```

My source says that:

```
frequency for variable declaration is 2

frequency for assignment statement is 2
```

But for this code :

```
int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
   for(int j=i+1;j<N;j++)
       if(a[i] + a[j] == 0)
           count++;
```

It says that:

```
frequency for variable declaration is N+2

frequency for assignment statement is N+2.
```

I couldn't understand why the results are N+2's for the second code.I thought that it should be 3 for variable declaration.Could you tell me the difference of these 2 code parts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. That's right because `j` is declared once for each iteration of `i`. So N times for `j` and then 2 times for `i` and `count`.

In the first case using same logic you will see that there are 2 declarations.

Same goes for the assignment statement which is clear once you understand the declarations logic.

```
int count=0; <--- declaration +1
for(int i=0;i<N;i++) <--- int i = 0 <-- +1
   for(int j=i+1;j<N;j++)  <-- i=0,1,2..N-1 <-- N times
       if(a[i] + a[j] == 0)
           count++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `j` is declared within `i`'s loop. Therefore, it will be declared on every iteration of the loop. There are `N` iterations of `i`'s loop, so it will be declared `N` times. `i` will be declared once and `count` will be declared once, so in total it's `N + 2` declarations.

Likewise for the assignments.

Answer (score 0):

In this -

```
int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)         
   for(int j=i+1;j<N;j++)    
       if(a[i] + a[j] == 0)
           count++;
```

`j` in inner loop is declared as many times the upper loop iterates which is `N` times. This is because for every iteration of upper loop, inner loop starts again.

And `count` and `i` are declared once. Therefore, you get `N+2` frequency.